# Trace inequality for a simple random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, random-matrices

I have two random vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, with joint probability law $P(x,y)$, and each has zero mean, $\mathbb{E} x = \mathbb{E} y = 0$. I build the rank-one matrix $M = xy^\intercal$. My goal is to show that:
$$|\text{Tr}[(\mathbb{E} M)^2]| \leq (\mathbb{E} \text{Tr} M)^2$$

Or as a function of $x,y$, 
$$|\text{Tr}[(\mathbb{E} xy^\intercal)^2]| \leq (\mathbb{E} x^\intercal y)^2$$

I tried to use Cauchy-Schwartz but couldn't get the result. If you have any leads please let me know :)

Comment: Note that when $n = 1$ or when x,y are non-random, this is an equality. So maybe it is actually again an equality when $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $u,v\stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\operatorname{Unif}(\{-1,1\}),\ x=(u,v)^T$ and $y=(u,-v)^T$. That is, suppose the $xy^T$ is uniformly distributed over the sample space
\begin{aligned}
&\left\{\pmatrix{1\\ 1}\pmatrix{1&-1},
\ \pmatrix{1\\ -1}\pmatrix{1&1},
\ \pmatrix{-1\\ 1}\pmatrix{-1&-1},
\ \pmatrix{-1\\ -1}\pmatrix{-1&1}\right\}\\
=\, &\left\{\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&-1},
\ \pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&-1},
\ \pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&-1},
\ \pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&-1}\right\}.
\end{aligned}
Then $E(xy^T)=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1}$ and $\operatorname{tr}\left((E(xy^T))^2\right)=2>0=\left(\operatorname{tr}(E(xy^T))\right)^2=\left(E(\operatorname{tr}(xy^T))\right)^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! I have another related question : is it true that $\text{Tr}[(E(xy^T))^2] \geq 0$ ?

Comment: @seamp No. In the answer above, if we flip the two rows of $x$ but keep the definition of $y$ unchanged, i.e. if $x=(v,u)^T$ instead, then the two rows of $E(xy^T)$ are flipped too, i.e. $E(xy^T)=\pmatrix{&-1\\ 1}$. Now the trace of the square of $E(xy^T)$ becomes $-2$.